# How to extract info from Association?

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

How can one extract a list of keys and a list of values from the association?

e.g. `as = <|a->1, b->2, c->3, d->4|>`

```
lst1 = {a, b, c, d}
lst2 = {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate as though this is a special case I feel everyone is better served by the redirect rather than closure.  The association can be converted to rules with `Normal`, then any of the methods given there may be used.  Or you can just use `Keys` and `Values` directly.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst1 = Keys @ as
lst2 = Values @ as
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d}
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

Or

```
{lst1, lst2} = Transpose @ KeyValueMap[List, as];

lst1
lst2
```

> ```
> {a, b, c, d}
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```